How to tell WebStorm NOT to use WSL?
I am using WebStorm on Windows 11
The problem is: WebStorm tries to run commands using a WSL path.

WebStorm tries to run the command using:
/mnt/c/Users/..../WebstormProjects/..../node_modules/.bin/nest

and the command fails with "16: exec: node: not found" message.
Which is a path that looks like WSL, the weird thing is that it used to work using the normal path C:/Users... but suddenly it stopped working.
I have not tried anything as I'm have no idea where to start.

What do you see in File > Settings > Tools > Terminals  --  Is WSL selected as default?

Hello @Zak the selected terminal is: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
